# How do I input multiple arguments into strip() function?

Tags: python, strip

today I was tasked to create a program that takes a user input and prints out the vowels and constants of what the user input was. I thought I was doing good so far but then I got an error while trying to use strip(). The error said the max arguments it could take were 1 and I was putting in multiple. How should I go about this?

```js
lst1 = ['a','e','i','o','u']

lst2 = ['b','c','d','f','g','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','s','t','v','x','z','h','r','w','y']

lst3 = [] ### this is for vowels

lst4 = [] ### this is for userinput

lst5 = [] ### this is for constants

def vowelstrip(lst4):
    



maxlength = 1
while len(lst4) < maxlength:
    lst4 = input('Enter a line of text: ')
    lst3 = lst4.strip('b','c','d','f','g','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','s','t','v','x','z','h','r','w','y')
    lst5 = lst4.strip('a','e','i','o','u')
    print(f'vowels are: {lst3}\n Constants are: {lst5}')
```

Comment: [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is a method of [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) class which accept single `str` argument, you're trying to pass more than one. *(Follow link to method's docs, there's an example)*

Comment: Do you want the word with the values removed? e.g. `apple -> (a, e), (p, p, l)`, Or do you want the unique vowels and consonants? e.g. `apple -> (a, e), (l, p)`

Comment: the program needs to print out the vowels and constants like in the print statement so it would have to take the user input, find all the vowels and print out what they are. Then do the same for the constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `strip` remove multiple characters by specifying them as a single string (not multiple arguments), but it only removes characters from the beginning and end of a string, not the middle, so it's not really suitable for what you're trying to do:

```
>>> "foobar".strip("rf")
'ooba'
>>> "foobar".strip("aeiou")
'foobar'
```

I'd suggest using a generator expression and `join` to build a new string by iterating over the user's input:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'


def extract_vowels(text: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(c for c in text if c in vowels)


def extract_consonants(text: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(c for c in text if c.isalpha() and c not in vowels)


text = input('Enter a line of text: ')
print(f'vowels are: {extract_vowels(text)}')
print(f'consonants are: {extract_consonants(text)}')
```

```
Enter a line of text: the quick brown fox
vowels are: euioo
consonants are: thqckbrwnfx
```

Comment: You don't really need string formatting there, just pass function call as second argument.